# Simple REST web server in docker container

Tags: linux, web-services, rest, docker

I would like a small web server that offers a REST api, that external tools can call to store very small amount of data (either write or read data) and offer a html page to display that data.

The data would be a simple matrix (2d table). I was planning on having external tools sending a single entry of the data with the REST api (one square of the table) in json format (it will contain only about three strings). Maybe store the data in a xml file.

I would like that web server to be in a docker container, so it can be deployed easily in our cloud environment (using a volume so in does not lose data). It would run under a Linux environment.

I know this is kind of a broad question, but I would like to know what technology to use for that case. Should I use Python? I don't actually know how to do that. I did docker containers in the past for other things, did some REST api in JAVA, but nothing like this.

Do you have suggestions or resources?

Comment: My advice (which suggests this is an opinion based question and will be closed) is Node.js in Docker. https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/apigee/api-microservices-with-nodejs-and-docker

Comment: Forget about docker for a while. First build the app you want to build, in the technology you want, so you can learn about how to build a webapp, and then try to use Docker. Otherwise you'll spread to thin and get demotivated when you spend 3 days trying to figure out why something is not working.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Python Flask to easily create a REST service and containerize . A tutorial available [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/docker-explained-how-to-containerize-python-web-applications)
Also you can try out spring-boot using which you can package a web container like tomcat along with which will be similar to your requirement . [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)